# OnKeyDown event in WebView not handled - Android

Tags: android, button, webview, back

I cannot achieve to call the Back button on an Android inside a WebView. I tried with `OnKeyDown`, `OnKey`, `OnBackPressed`
My current code is the following :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final Activity activity = this;
    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView!=null && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

The error says that the function `OnKeyDown` is not implemented... Any idea ?
Thank you really much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
            return true;
    }

}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

UPDATE :IF ABOVE CODE FAILS ,TRY THIS

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

   if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the error is still :Unimplemented WebView method onKeyDown called from: android.webkit.WebView.onKeyDown(WebView.java:2178) @salih kallai

Comment: try to remove private modifier of your webview,May be work

Comment: change 'mWebView.goBack();' to 'WebView.goBack();'

Comment: "non static method goback() cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: I managed to do it ! Thank you really much... Actually I did it in the js called on the index page : 
function onBackKeyDown() {
$$(".back").click();
}
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);